# How do I check if the given number is the sum of a list slice?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion, slice

I have a `python` `list` consist of integers. I need to find whether the given number is `sum(mylist[some slice])`

```
a = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 6]
num = 22
Answer will be either [3, 3, 5, 5, 6] or [5, 5, 6, 6]
#'.' sum([3, 3, 5, 5, 6]) == 22 || sum([5, 5, 6, 6]) == 22
```

So far I have done something like a recursive way. **Note: I am getting  the expected output**

```
def find_slice(mylist, num, extra=2):
    if len(mylist) == 0:
        return None

    for i in range( len(mylist )-1):
        if sum( mylist[:extra + i] ) == num:
            return mylist[ :extra + i]

    return find_slice(mylist[1:], num, extra+1)

>>> a = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 6]

>>> print(find_slice(a, 22))
[3, 3, 5, 5, 6]
```

In terms of time complexity, it takes `O(n!)` **(N factorial)**.

How can I modify this in terms of `time complexity` and `space complexity`? Or Is there any better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a window while you are iterating over your items:

```
a = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 6]
num = 22
def find_slice(mylist, num):
    window = []
    for e in a:
        window.append(e)
        s = sum(window)

        if s > num:
            window.pop(0)
            while sum(window) > num:
                window.pop(0)
            s = sum(window)

        if s == num:
            return window

print(find_slice(a, num))
# [3, 3, 5, 5, 6]
```

this will be O(n) time complexity and O(n) space

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [@kederrac's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61292634/how-do-i-check-if-the-given-number-is-the-sum-of-a-list-slice/61293328#61293328) sliding window solution, its worth mentioning that popping the first item with `pop(0)` is `O(N)`, whereas popping the last item from the end with `pop(-1)` is `O(1)`. We can see this comparison in the [Time Complexity - Python Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

We can make popping the first item `O(1)` using [`popleft`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.deque.popleft) from [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

> Remove and return an element from the left side of the deque. If no elements are present, raises an IndexError.

**Modified code:**

```
from collections import deque

a = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 6]
num = 22

def find_slice(mylist, num):
    window = deque() 
    for e in a:
        window.append(e)
        s = sum(window)

        if s > num:
            window.popleft()
            while sum(window) > num:
                window.popleft()
            s = sum(window)

        if s == num:
            return window

print(list(find_slice(a, num)))
# [3, 3, 5, 5, 6]
```

The solution above should now be approximately `O(N * W)`, where `N` is the number of elements in the list, and `W` is the window size. I don't think you can get much better than this.